# How to get all specific values from an array of objects with nested arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree, logic

I have an array:

```
   const arr = [
  {
    name: "name 1",
    dontShow: true,
    children: [
      {
        name: "name 2",
        key4: 4,
        dontShow: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "name 3",
    dontShow: false,
    children: [
      {
        name: "name 4",
        dontShow: true,
        children: [
          {
            name: "name 5",
            dontShow: false,
            children: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need an array of names from every object, except those that have property `dontShow: true`
So from that example I would expect such array:

```
["name2", "name3", "name5"]
```

Basically, I need to get a flat array from tree-like structure, lodash/underscore solutions would be also great, I just didn't find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function

```js
const arr = [{ name: "name 1", dontShow: true, children: [{  name:"name 2", key4: 4, dontShow: false, children: [], }, ],},{name: "name 3",dontShow: false,children: [{ name: "name 4", dontShow: true, children: [{ name: "name 5", dontShow: false, children: null,},],}, ],},];

let final = (arr, result = []) => {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    arr.forEach(obj => {
      if (!obj.dontShow) {
        result.push(obj.name)
      }
      if (Array.isArray(obj.children)) {
        final(obj.children, result)
      }
    })
  }
  return result
}

console.log(final(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a flat array of names with a look to `dontShow`.

```js
const
    getNames = array => array.flatMap(({ name, dontShow, children }) => [
        ...(dontShow ? [] : [name]),
        ...getNames(children || [])
    ]),
    array = [{ name: "name 1", dontShow: true, children: [{ name: "name 2", key4: 4, dontShow: false, children: [] }] }, { name: "name 3", dontShow: false, children: [{ name: "name 4", dontShow: true, children: [{ name: "name 5", dontShow: false, children: null, }] }] }],
    result = getNames(array);

console.log(result);
```